# Могучее государство готов погибло

Tags: грамматика

Это - отрывок из Гумилева.  Он находится в начале первой главы "От Руси к России", в части "Готы", в первом предложении, в последнем абзаце.  Полное предложение выглядит так:

> Могучее государство готов погибло, как это нередко бывало, из-за измены подданных и жестокости правителя.

Я не понимаю, почему предложение построено таким образом.  То есть, словосочетание "могучее государство" - среднего рода, а "готов" - мужского.  Я написал бы "могучее государство готово погибать...". Возможно, я не понимаю смысл.

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не рано в первом главе, а в начале первой главы.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Дело в том, что "го́тов" в данном случае - это существительное во множественном числе родительном падеже, ударение падает на первый слог. "[Го́ты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B)" это название древнего германского народа.

Comment: Ах!  Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @JohnS the name of the chapter gives you a hint )))

Comment: @JohnS By the way, "Ах" is not used in this particular meaning in Russian (it is more like an emotional, delighted or surprised gasp). To show you  suddenly feel you now understand something, you may use "А-а" (А-а-а). I wonder if good dictionaries on the topic exist. :) Explaining typical fillers in speech is a pain for sure. Native speakers use it bases solely on intuition.